# reporting on event hits in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have been tasked with using Google Analytics to report of use of a desktop app so we can see which parts of the program are being used and how heavily, and potentially also see which companies are using which parts of the program (each company has a unique companyID). Ideally I'd like to be able to look at correlations (e.g., How many users who use report A also use process B?)

I currently have my program set to fire off a call to analytics. I've set it up to use the event tracking, but I'm open to app/screen tracking or something else if something would work better. I'm passing values like

```
v=1
&t=event                // Event hit type
&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y         // our ID; real code has valid value here
&cid=12345              // CustomerID
&ec=JobFinancialReport  // Event Category
&ea=Run                 // Event Action
&el=Manager             // Event label
&ev=7                   // Event value
```

What I can't figure out is how in Google Analytics to set up reports that would show me something like:

```
CustomerID     Category             Label    Total Hits    Unique Users
12345          JobFinancialReport   Manager     27              2
12345          MarketingReport1     Manager      6              4
```

I'm totally new to analytics so pardon my ignorance if I have some key misconception here. I've searched Googles sites and other questions here, but I may be wording my question incorrectly so I'm not finding something that's there. This is only one example; in some cases we might want to see how broadly each customer is using the program; in other cases we'd want to take the customerID out and just see how much a particular report is being used overall. Appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "cid" parameter is the [client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId), the value that is used to stitch single interactions into sessions and users.

The first problem that comes to mind with your setup is that the client id is not exposed in the user interface (with the single exception of the user explorer report) or the API.

You would need to implement this via a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) (probably user scope, since it probably will never change for a given user) where you pass in the client id (you still need the cid parameter).

Then you could create a custom report (or create a report in Google Data Studio) with the custom value as primary dimension and your selected metric.

If you want to report "Unique Users" you would probably need to create a cid per logged-in user (if all users of the app have the same cid then you will always have but a single user reported). You should then probably create a second custom dimension for the company id, so you can segment your reports by company.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any advantage in use event tracking vs. screen tracking? Events seem harder to get info on with some views of info.

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom reports in google analytics to get your desired output. here is how to create custom reports https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en